# Automatically size width to fit children and go off page

Tags: css, html

I have an annoying issue that has been bugging me for a while. Pretty much, I have a div, which contains a ul, which then contains a series of li's. Here is some source:

```
<div>
    <ul>
        <li>Foo</li>
        <li>Bar</li>
        <li>Some text here</li>
    </ul>
</div>
```

I have it set out so that the different elements tile across the screen, like in this image..
[image: Diagram of elements]
Except without the scroll bar down the bottom. What I am trying to do is add a scroll bar so that you can scroll across. I don't know how many elements I would have, however, I do know the size of each box and the spacing inbetween them. If you still don't understand what I am trying to do, check out the project [here](http://products.mrfishie.com/playzone/index.php?p=my%20awesome%20game). The part that I am trying to do is the row of elements on the top. I want them to have a horizontal scroll bar.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I looked at the site you referenced. The `<li>` elements are in `display: inline-block`, which is not going to work. Try this: Replace your current CSS for `ul li` with:

```
ul li {
    list-style: none;
    display: table-cell;
    border: 10px solid transparent;
    border-top: none;
    border-bottom: none;
}
```

Which makes all the list elements align in only one row, instead of overflowing into multiple rows.

Also, please try to include more code, or add it into a [JSFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net).

Comment: I have tried doing that, but the content will not expand beyond the width of the div. And also, if you want to view what I mean, click the link.

Answer (score 0):

You can specify a width to your `div` and apply the `overflow:auto` css property to it. It'll make the scrollbar visibile if the elements width are higher than the div's width.

```
<style>
.my_div {
   width:600px;
   overflow-x:auto;
}
</style>

<div class='my_div'>
    <ul>
        <li>Foo</li>
        <li>Bar</li>
        <li>Some text here</li>
    </ul>
</div>
```

Answer (score 0):

```
<div style="overflow-x: auto; width:100%;">
    <ul>
        <li>Foo</li>
        <li>Bar</li>
        <li>Some text here</li>
    </ul>
</div>
```

and to li's

```
   li {
      float: left:
      // or
      display: inline;
    }
```

Answer (score 0):

**CSS:**

```
#header-container
{
    width:100%; /* or set it to whatever you want */
    overflow-x: auto;
}
```

**HTML:**

```
<div id="header-container">
    <ul>
        <li>Foo</li>
        <li>Bar</li>
        <li>Some text here</li>
    </ul>
</div>
```

Done!

Comment: As I have said, the elements still seem to want to wrap to the next line.